# What is a place?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

In [Specialization of Quadratic
and Symmetric Bilinear
Forms](http://www-nw.uni-regensburg.de/~knm22087/book.pdf) (page: 3) the author writes "Let also $\lambda: K \to L \cup \infty$ be a place, $\mathfrak o = \mathfrak o_\lambda$ the valuation ring associated to $K$ and $\mathfrak m$ be the maximal ideal of $\mathfrak o$."

What is a *place* and what is $L$? This is the first page of the book so that knowledge of the definition seems to be assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some definitions in:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field#Places)
- *Algebraic Number Theory*, J. Neukirch - chapter III starts with a definition of places. Valuations are defined in chapter II.
- *Algebraic Number Theory*, E. Weiss - places are defined much earlier in the book (in the first few pages), but I personally like this book a little less than Neukirch.